# Add a class to "price-box" depending on product option selection [Magento 2.4.4]

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have configurable products with options of 'sample' and 'length'. I would like to add a class (either 'sam' or 'len') to `<div class="price-box">` depending on which option is chosen so I can display a different suffix after the price. e.g. '£20.00 ea.' or '£100.00 per m.'

Comment: Hi. Have you found a solution for this?